# Torch no me permite multiplicar matrices con las mismas dimensiones

Tags: python, pytorch

Estoy intentando implementar un algoritmo basado en Deep Reinforcement Learning, estoy utilizando torch y en un metodo que tiene llamado forward me da el siguiente error:

> RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x33 and 1x33)

Ambas matrices tienen las mismas dimensiones, y ambas son tensores de torch.

Comment: En la multiplicación de matrices, las dimensiones internas deben coincidir y el resultado tendrá las dimensiones externas. Es decir, puedes hacer una multiplicación de matrices de 1x33@33x1 o de 33x1@1x33, pero no de 1x33@1x33 (dónde @ es el símbolo de multiplicación de matrices). Encontrarás más información en https://www.learnpytorch.io/pytorch_most_common_errors/